# Can a process be shifted by some $cn$ and it retains martingale? Martingale linearity?

Tags: martingales

Can a process be shifted by some $cn$ and it retains martingale? Martingale linearity?

Particularly the problem in my case is that:

My process is defined by $M_n=Y_n-cn$, $c>0$, where $Y_n=f(X_1,...,X_n)$ is known as sub-martingale process.

My $F_n = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$.

By linearity of conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_n|F_n]-\mathbb{E}[cn|F_n]$$

Clearly this also doesn't violate measurability.

I can estimate this down:

$$\geq Y_{n-1}-\mathbb{E}[cn|F_n]$$

But what then?

I've checked:

- I'm not sure whether I can say that $cn$ depends or doesn't depend on $F_n$, since I don't have information about $X_i$ except for $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$, they are i.i.d., bounded
- I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do something like "let $cn=\text{ some r.v. I know }$".
- It's possible to say: $cn\mathbb{E}[1|F_n]$, but I'm not sure if this is any simpler.

Comment: Since $cn$ is constant, it is independent of $F_n$. So $\mathbb E[cn\mid F_n] = \mathbb E[cn] = cn$.

Comment: @Math1000 How can we know that $cn$ would not coincide with the values of some $X_i$s?

Comment: $\omega\mapsto cn$ is a degenerate random variable and therefore independent of any $\sigma$-algebra.